# Migration Core Data error code 134130

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I want to do migration with 2 CoreData databases. I have read [apple developer document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH4-SW1).

For the first database, I added some attributes (string, integer and date properties) to new version of database. And following all steps, I have done migration successfully with the first one.

But the second database, I also added attributes (string, integer, date, transformable and binary-data properties) to new version of database. And following all steps (like with the first database) the system returns an error (134130).

Here is the code:

```
if (persistentStoreCoordinator_) {
    PMReleaseSafely(persistentStoreCoordinator_);
}

// Notify
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc postNotificationName:GCalWillMigrationNotification object:self];

//
NSString *sourceStoreType = NSSQLiteStoreType;
NSString *dataStorePath = [PMUtility dataStorePathForName:GCalDBWarehousePersistentStoreName];
NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dataStorePath];
BOOL storeExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataStorePath];

//
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
persistentStoreCoordinator_ = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel];
[persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:sourceStoreType
                                          configuration:nil
                                                    URL:storeURL
                                                options:options
                                                  error:&error];
if (error != nil) {
    abort();
}
```

Error is not nil and below is log:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "The operation
couldn\u2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)" UserInfo=0x856f790
{URL=file://localhost/Users/greensun/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/D10712DE-D9FE-411A-8182-C4F58C60EC6D/Library/Application%20Support/XXX/XXX.sqlite,
metadata={type = immutable dict,
count = 7, entries =>   2 : {contents =
"NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers"} = {type = immutable, count = 1, values = (    0 : {contents = ""} )}    4 : {contents = "NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion"} = {value = +386, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}    6 :
{contents =
"NSStoreModelVersionHashes"} = {type = immutable dict, count = 2, entries =>   0 :
{contents = "XXX"} = {length = 32, capacity = 32, bytes =
0xfdae355f55c13fbd0344415fea26c8bb ... 4c1721aadd4122aa}    1 :
{contents = "XXX"} = {length = 32, capacity = 32, bytes =
0x7676888f0d7eaff4d1f844343028ce02 ... 040af6cbe8c5fd01} }  7 :
{contents = "NSStoreUUID"} = {contents =
"51678BAC-CCFB-4D00-AF5C-8FA1BEDA6440"}     8 : {contents = "NSStoreType"} = {contents = "SQLite"}   9 : {contents = "_NSAutoVacuumLevel"} = {contents = "2"}    10 : {contents = "NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion"} =
{value = +3, type =
kCFNumberSInt32Type} }, reason=Can't find model for source store}
```

I tried a lot of solutions, but it does not work. I just add more attributes to 2 new version database, and succeed in migrating once.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Apple framework in iOS5. I assume you are a member of Apple iOS Developer Program, so you can read about it here in [Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/666466#666466).

In short it means that if you have more than one model as you do with two persistent stores for example (but not only then), you cannot in some occasions add a new version of one data model while other models remain at their current versions.

It has been submitted to Apple and marked as duplicate. I do not know if this has been fixed in iOS6 yet.

Comment: Thanks for reponse my question.

Comment: I have solved my problem.
I have been working with SVN and when I created new version of Core Date, SVN also created a copy of old version data.
I have to make a copy outside and remove total Core Data from SVN in project. Then, I create new Core Data and it solved my problem.